# Trying to run java program for running windows command, but program is not working

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I'm trying to run windows commands by using java code, but code is not working and giving exception error. 
Following is the code

```
import java.io.*; 

public class run_command
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
       try  
       {
         String command = "start firefox";
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        }
        catch(IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }
    }
}
```

And following is the exception error

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start firefox": Create
>   Process error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

This error is occurring for every windows commands. Please suggest some solution on this.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run program `start` with parameter `firefox`:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start", "firefox");
```

`start` is an executable, so is `firefox`, but there is no such executable named `start firefox`.

Comment: but I've also tried with command set path="{PATH}" but its not working its giving same error that is 'Cannot run program "set"'

Comment: @Omkar `set` is an internal command, you have to call it using `cmd set`.

Comment: I’m pretty sure `start` is built into cmd and is not an executable.  Where is it located on your system?